# Did we ever see Professor Charles Xavier control animals?

Tags: marvel, x-men

In the movie, *Logan* (2017), we have seen Charles Xavier

> [controlling, or at least nudging horses to some extent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAwc1XIOFME).

Did he ever control any animal other than humans in any other movies? Did he ever get into the head of an animal in any comics or cartoons?

Comment: Can he grunt and squeak and squawk with the animals?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Well, yes.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professor_X#Powers_and_abilities):

> He is one of the few telepaths skilled enough to communicate with animals and even share their perceptions.

Backing this up with one specific occurrence in *X-Men Legacy #211* where Charles uses his ability control a band of pigeons to attack a sniper who was trying to kill him.

[image: Panel 1: Close up on Xavier's face, he thinks: "The mind-scape of any place is a continuous weaving. Human minds are only a apart of it, as are birds, small animals, even insects. A blank space in that weaving means one thing and one thing only." Panel 2: We see Xavier stood at the back of a black car with his hands on the boot looking behind himself. In the background we see a purple car parked and a hospital, he thinks: "It means someone nearby is using a mind-shield. I think I need to know why." Panel 3: Close up on a pigeon in front of the bright sun, he thinks "So I use the tools that come most readily to hand."]
 <sub>*Click image to enlarge*</sub>

[image: Panel 1: Overhead view showing a sniper on top of a building aiming down at Xavier at the back of the car, Xavier thinks "In the pigeon's perception, the man on the roof counts as neither food nor threat. He blends into the background--seen and then forgotten." Panel 2: Close up on the sniper looking worried as he begins to get surrounded by pigeons, Xavier thinks "Probably, I should be ashamed of this. Probably my rules of engagement need to be more rigidly defined. Like--first, do no harm." Panel 3: The pigeons swarm the sniper who begins to back away and panic, Xavier thinks "Well, I'll do as little harm as I can. As little as it takes to throw him off his aim." Panel 4: Xavier now in the black saloon races off down the street knocking a bin over, in the background the pigeons can be seen still swarming the sniper on the roof, Xavier thinks "And shelve this small enigma until the larger one is resolved."]
 <sub>*Click image to enlarge*</sub>

---

Thanks to [@Valorum's comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/235937/did-we-ever-see-xavier-control-animals#comment647004_235937), another occurrence of Xavier "talking" is seen in *X-Men Legacy #218* where he uses a parrot for recon.

[image: Panel 1: The view through Logan's binoculars at a jungle island showing a large mansion surrounded by a barbed wire fend, he says "There's the house. Hard to miss because it's the only structure on the island. On the map it's a weather monitoring station." Panel 2: Logan kneels at the front of the craft looking over the island offering the binoculars to Xavier who stands at the back with paddle in hand also looking, Logan: "You want to take a look?" "No, thank you, Logan. I'm already there." "How's that?" Panel 3: Close on Xavier's face behind a parrot sat in the trees, he says to Logan "I found a bird in the jungle canopy and flew it in low over the compound. It's sitting in a baobab tree, now, just behind the villa's swimming pool." Panel 4: overhead view of the barbed wire fence surrounding the villa, Xavier says: "The fence doesn't seem to carry current, but it's twenty feet high and topped with razor wire. And the earth is disturbed for thirty feet around it. We'll have to look out for mines."]
 <sub>*Click image to enlarge*</sub>

Comment: “he uses a parrot for recon” — man, that parrot could do so much more for the cause. Get it on some talk shows. “BWARRRK! Humans and mutants can live together in peace! BWARRRK!” I, for one, am convinced.

Answer (score 15):

There is a deleted scene from *X-Men: First Class* that suggests that, at least in the X-Men Cinematic Universe, Charles Xavier cannot telepathically control animals.

In the scene Charles uses his powers to make it seem that the truck that he, Eric and a number of US soldiers are hiding in, is empty. In the scene he is able to convince the soviet soldiers who are checking the content of the truck that there is no one inside, but he is unable to control their dog who keeps barking at them.

> **Eric:** "Can't you control it?"
>
> **Charles:** "Doesn't work on animals. Too stupid I think."

As this is only a deleted scene, it can of course not be treated as canon for the X-Men Cinematic Universe.